# Explain the behaviour of the `every` method of ES6

Tags: javascript

I just want to convince myself if what I'm thinking here is correct.

```
var num = [1, 2, 3];
num.every(i=> Number.isInteger(i)) // returns true checking if every number in the list is integer which is fine

num.every(i=> console.log(i)) //Prints only the first element which is 1.
```

The question is in the second case, why doesn't `console.log(i)` gets executed for each of the elements?

Now what I'm thinking is this.

`every` takes a callback function as an argument. While, `Number.isInteger(i)` keeps returning true for each of the elements, `console.log(i)` prints the first element and **returns false** and hence it doesn't get executed for the later elements. Am I correct in thinking this?

Comment: Almost, it returns `undefined`, which is falsey

Comment: @CertainPerformance Yup exactly

Comment: console.log returns undefined whic becomes falsy and the `every` stops. To make it continue it could be done like: `num.every(i=> console.log(i) + "" )`

Comment: why `every` when you really need to use `forEach` ...?

Comment: @MohsenAlyafei yup, that pretty much confirms it! Thanks!

Comment: @MohsenAlyafei `num.every(i=>!console.log(i));` would work as well.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as an iteration does not return `true` there's no point in keep iterating.

`console.log` doesn't return anything (actually, `undefined`), so after running it once, `every` just evaluates false and terminates.

Then yes, it's pretty much as you though :)

Comment: There is no mandate that ‘true’ is returned for the positive case.